# Put observable on a modal button click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a dynamic array of lets say 7 items maybe 10 items.  For each item i need to show a modal but it has to be sequential and the next modal in the loop pops up only when the user clicks ok.

What is the simplest way to handle this?

```
export class Modal {

    openModal: boolean = false;
    message: string = 'Yes';
    @Input: ErrorList;

    for (const error of ErrorList.Errors) { 

        // Need to show each modal here. 
        // But also need to wait for the user to click a button in order to show 
        // the next modal
        this.ShowModal(error);
    }

    ShowModal(error) {
        this.message = error;
        this.openModal = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when they hit cancel?What library are you using for the model? Can you add some code that you have tried already?

Comment: Modals interrupt the user flow and make it impossible to interact with the parent page by hiding the content behind the modal. Most users despise modals. Why would you subject a user to a series of them?

Comment: George that makes sense. I was given a task to show users a list of errors in a modal before they upload a file.  The error shows the user what is wrong with the file before they upload it and each error gives the user an option to clear the row or append to it. What suggestions do you have other than showing them modals?

Comment: Shyam I have added the code for where I am starting.